# How to turn a cell in excel to a hyperlink using the value of the cell at the end of the url

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a program in VBA within Excel everything works perfectly except the part that takes the value of the cell and adds it to the end of a hyperlink, then adds the hyperlink to the cell displaying the value. Here is the code I am using for this part:

```
'Hyper Link column A

Dim WorkRng As Range
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", "Select Range", WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

Dim l As Long
Dim addr As String
For l = WorkRng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If WorkRng.Cells(l, 1).Value <> "" Then
        addr = CStr("https://True&RequestID=") & CStr(WorkRng.Cells(l, 1).Value)
        WorkRng.Cells(l, 1).Hyperlink.Add Anchor:=WorkRng.Cells(l, 1), _
        Address:=addr, _
        TextToDisplay:=CStr(WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value)
    End If
Next
```

It keeps breaking at this part:

```
        WorkRng.Cells(l, 1).Hyperlink.Add Anchor:=WorkRng.Cells(l, 1), _
        Address:=addr, _
        TextToDisplay:=CStr(WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value)
```

Any advice would be very helpful.

Comment: I think you're missing an `s` on the end of `Hyperlink` - it's [`Hyperlinks.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlinks.add).

Comment: Awesome that fixed the hyperlink issue but it only does the first cell and stops

Comment: What's `i` in `TextToDisplay:=CStr(WorkRng.Cells(i, 1).Value)`? You've declared `l` but not `i`. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module.

Comment: Did I seriously do that, well I fixed that part but it didnt even get that far the problem is here: `Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", "Select Range", WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)`

Comment: Can you be more specific on what the problem is? Error message?

Comment: Its not an error message I get its that I have to manually select to the end of the row to insert it, and actually Im not sure it is adding the url and the cell value. Ok it does enter it correctly but does automatically do it for all of the values @Big

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. In any case, it probably should be its own separate question, maybe with more explanation on what you're trying to do and how the current code is failing.... I think we've resolved the main issue(s) with your this question, which were typos.

Comment: Ok will do that in the morning, tyvm